# jquery div animation on 3 divs in same spot issue

Tags: jquery

I'm not exactly sure how to word my issue so i'll explain it as best i can.

I have just the homepage on my website and i'm trying to change the main area content dynamically with jquery, heres what i have right now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        $("#div2").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        $("#div3").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $("#div1").delay(501).show("slide", {direction: "down" }, 500);
});

    $('#link2').click(function(){
        $("#div1").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        $("#div3").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $("#div2").delay(501).show("slide", {direction: "down" }, 500);
});
    $('#link3').click(function(){
        $("#div2").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        $("#div1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $("#div3").delay(501).show("slide", {direction: "down" }, 500);
}); });
```

My issue is if i click a link that hides a div that isnt currently showing, it shows the div THEN hides it.

How do i combat this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking.
It would be best if you can provide a fiddle with an example.

You can simply check if the div is visible, and run the sliding animation only if it is visible.

For example:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    if ($('#div2').is(':visible')){
        $("#div2").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
    }

    if ($('#div3').is(':visible')){
        $("#div3").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    }

    $("#div1").delay(501).show("slide", {direction: "down" }, 500);
});
```

Another thing, I suggest you use classes instead of ids. It doesn't make much sense to write all the possible combination. Imagine you have 10 links... it is a lot of unnecessary code